# call function with array parameters postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have the following function:

```
create or replace function getEdit (farm bigint [], retreat bigint [], dateLot date)
returns integer as $$
declare
qtde bigint = 0;
begin
select sum (e.est_qtde) into qtde
   from stocked and
   left join catanimal c on c.can_chave = e.can_chave
   left join farm f on f.faz_chave = e.faz_chave
  where e.cfg_chave = 1922
    and e.est_data <= $ 3
    and COALESCE (c.can_situation, 0) = 0
    and COALESCE (f.faz_situacao, 0) = 0
    and e.faz_chave in ($1::bigint[])
    and e.ret_key in ($2::bigint[]);
    return qtde;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

when you call it:

```
select * from getSet (array [19220200006, 19220200005], array [19220200005, 19220200004], '2019-03-01')
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bigint []
LINE 8: and e.faz_chave in ($ 1 :: bigint [])
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need PL/pgSQL for this. A simply `language sql` function would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an array you need to use the `ANY` operator:

```
and e.faz_chave = ANY (farm)
and e.ret_key = ANY (retreat);
```

There is no need to cast the parameter to the same type it was declared.